# Kurento : Error installing custom module

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, gstreamer, kurento

I am trying to install my custom module debian file in one of my ubuntu machine but I an getting following error:

```
Unpacking mycustom-filter (1.2.0~rc1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mycustom-filter:
 mycustom-filter depends on libgstreamer-plugins-base1.5-0 (>= 1.8.1.1~20160608155102.55.g7b19cfd.trusty); however:
  Version of libgstreamer-plugins-base1.5-0:amd64 on system is 1.8.0~20160530103212.387.g21728a3.trusty.
 mycustom-filter depends on libgstreamer1.5-0 (>= 1.8.1.1~20160706093049.167.g0d8d50e.trusty); however:
  Version of libgstreamer1.5-0:amd64 on system is 1.8.0~20160530103131.368.g0fb3a08.trusty.
```

I see that there is a problem with the trusty version:

```
  mycustom-filter depends on libgstreamer-plugins-base1.5-0 (>= 1.8.1.1~20160608155102.55.g7b19cfd.trusty);
  mycustom-filter depends on libgstreamer1.5-0 (>= 1.8.1.1~20160706093049.167.g0d8d50e.trusty);
```

I tried uninstalling `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.5-0` and `libgstreamer1.5-0` but that messed up KMS installation.

now even after trying `autoclean` `clean` `apt-get update --fix-missing` I'm unable to install `libgstreamer1.5-0 (>= 1.8.1.1~20160706093049.167.g0d8d50e.trusty)`

it is always installing `1.8.0~20160530103131.368.g0fb3a08.trusty`

can any one guide me how to install the required `libgstreamer-plugins-base1.5-0` and `libgstreamer1.5-0` libraries.

**Edit 1:**
Facing the same issue for dev version of kurento

```
libgstreamer1.5-dev : Depends: libgstreamer1.5-0 (= 1.8.0~20160530103131.368.g0fb3a08.trusty) but 1.8.1.1~20160608134755.164.gb2c1df3.trusty is to be installed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this repository in your sources.list, instead of the previous one your were using.

`deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org/6.5.0 trusty kms6`

Comment: edited `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list`  and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kurento.list.save`
and replace `deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org trusty kms6` with `deb http://ubuntu.kurento.org/6.5.0 trusty kms6` 

FIXED the issue... Thank a lot guys..

Comment: You can go back to the kurento repository if you want. It should be fixed by now.

Comment: facing the same issue for `dev` version of kurento, `libgstreamer1.5-dev : Depends: libgstreamer1.5-0 (= 1.8.0~20160530103131.368.g0fb3a08.trusty) but 1.8.1.1~20160608134755.164.gb2c1df3.trusty is to be installed`

Answer (score 1):

There is a transitory problem on kurento repository that is being fixed right now. I'll edit this answer when is done.

As @igracia says, you can use 6.5.0 release repository to get the correct packages versions while the repository is broken.

**Edit**

It should be fixed now. Sorry for the trouble